# Explode textbox comma seperated into individual textbox's

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I'm trying to explode this text box into 5 INDIVIDUAL text box's.

Current result

```
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="2, simon feld,     1968, TAS" size="40">
```

Desired result

```
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="2" size="40">
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="simon feld" size="40">
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1968" size="40">
```

Comment: What is your desired output?please show a demo

Comment: all 3 inputs have the same name, you will have problems in this way. Better to change input name="textfield" ot input name="textfield[]". In that case you are putting the values in a array

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware that repeating `name` and `id` attributes makes them near-useless?

Comment: obviously the names need to be changed

Comment: why you need this desired out put may i know the reason ? is there any logic ?

Comment: textfield1 textfield2 etc

Comment: @jothi so I can control the elements /display submit etc simply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you can find the working example and [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2np8je6p/)

```
function makeSeperateInputs() {
var arrOfValues = $('#textfield').val().split(',');
for(var i=0, len = arrOfValues.length; i < len; i++) {
$('body').append('<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield' + i + '" value="' + arrOfValues[i] + '" size="40"><br>')
}
}
$('body').on('click', '#seperateThem', function() {
makeSeperateInputs()
})
```